# incorrect res.render using express and node

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, pug

I want to render the following using express and jade:

```
function(output) {
   for (i=0;i<output.entities.length;i++){
      console.log(output.entities[i].uuid);
   }
res.render('errCodes.jade', {title : 'Error Codes', entry: output.entities});
},
```

the jade looks like so:

```
items = entry
    each item, i in items
    li <a href="/#{i}">#{item}</a>
```

The console log looks nice, but no matter what I try, I can't get the jade page to look nice.  At the moment, there are two links that read

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

which is expected.  However, I want two links of the ID to show up, but every time I've tried I either get each character of the ID as its own link, or the aforementioned object, object.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your original indentation correct? or is it just here on SO that it looks wrong?

```
items = entry
  each item, i in items
  li <a href="/#{i}">#{item}</a> // this should be further right
```

You can use pure jade to achieve the same:

```
items = entry
  each item, i in items
    li
      a(href="/#{i}") #{item}
```

if your array looks like the following

```
output.entities = [{ uuid: 1234 }, { uuid: 5678 }];
```

your jade should look like this

```
items = entry
  each item, index in items // iterate over array
    li
      a(href="/#{index}") #{item.uuid}
```

`index` will be 1,2,3,4,... etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer; it took me a bit to figure out that jade was already handling arrays, I just needed to specify which part to display ( the #{item.uuid} )